# numpy: performing a cut-off spectral filter on a 2d velocity field, want to inverse to a coarser grid

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to take a velocity field, apply a spectral cut-off filter, and then plot the result on a grid that matches the coarseness of the filter.  This is where I'm at:

```
nx = 200
dx = 10.0
filterx = 100.0
px = np.arange(0,nx*dx,dx)

ratio = dx / filterx
nnx = int(nx*ratio)

raw = np.zeros((nx,nx))
raw2 = np.zeros((nx,nx))
for i in range(np.shape(raw)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(raw)[1]):
        raw[i,j] += 1.0*np.cos(i/dx/2.0*3.14) + 1.0*np.cos(j/dx/2.0*3.14)
        raw[i,j] += 2.0*np.cos(i*dx*50.0*3.14) + 2.0*np.cos(j*dx*50.0*3.14)
        raw2[i,j] = 1.0*np.cos(i/dx/2.0*3.14) + 1.0*np.cos(j/dx/2.0*3.14)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

plt.subplot(331)
plt.pcolor(px/dx,px/dx,raw)
plt.title("raw signal")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(332)
plt.pcolor(px/dx,px/dx,raw2)
plt.title("raw coarse signal")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.colorbar()

trn = (np.fft.fft2(raw))
k = (np.fft.fftfreq(nx,dx)) * dx*nx

for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(nx):
        if abs(nx*dx/np.float64(k[i])) < 2.0*filterx or abs(nx*dx/np.float64(k[j])) < 2.0*filterx:
            trn[i,j] = 0

itrn = np.fft.ifft2(trn)

plt.subplot(333)
plt.pcolor(px/dx,px/dx,itrn)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("fine")

plt.subplot(334)
plt.pcolor(px[::int(1.0/ratio)]/dx,px[::int(1.0/ratio)]/dx,itrn[::int(1.0/ratio),::int(1.0/ratio)])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("fine sampled")

itrns = np.fft.ifft2(trn,s=(nnx,nnx))

plt.subplot(335)
plt.pcolor(px[::int(1.0/ratio)]/dx,px[::int(1.0/ratio)]/dx,itrns)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("itrns")
```

which produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcjxY.png).  Let me stop here and explicitly say that I am not at all worried about the crudeness of my filter.

The filter works well enough, and I can plot the field back on its original grid no problem ("fine").  I can sample that "fine" field and plot it on a coarse grid ("fine sampled"), but that's cheating.  I would like to somehow tell the inverse transform that I want to drop the small scales.  The `ifft2()` function seems to have this option, and it very nearly works ("itrns"; sorry about the name on that one), but the magnitude is way off.

The degree to which it is off changes drastically depending on the size of the filter.  Is there some scaling that I could use that would work this out?